# Can anybody tell me the difference between these two velocity?

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, harmonic-oscillator

In Waves i earlier studied that

velocity of the wave is given $wa\sqrt{1-y^2}$

w= angular velocity 
a=amplitude of the wave 
y=post. of wave at any time

and now when i am studying wave optics velocity is given by

$ƒ*Λ$ 
f=frequency of the wave
^=wavelength of the wave

are these velocity anyhow related?

Comment: This should go without saying but define your variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$wa\sqrt{1-y^2}$ is the velocity of SHM  while $ƒ*Λ$  - velocity of on any wave